# How can I drop drag-able items into drop-zone which contains children drop-zones in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I'm facing a problem with Ext JS drag and drop zones and trying to make it works as I expected:

Please take a look into my [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vo0).

I want to create multiple overlapping drag-and-drop-zones like the attachment: [Drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk83L.png)

I have a main drop-zone panels and some panels within it (also are drop zones) and some drag-able items.

In my Fiddle, it works fine except:

- I can't drop items into drop-zones that inside another drop-zone(the
  1st panel - Drop zone 1).
- In the 3rd panel(title: "I'm not a drop zone"), I can drop items into its children.

I want to drag drag-able items into drop-zones, not only into parent drop-zone but also into its children drop-zones too.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible. Since the code to be able to drag and drop something, probably checks if the mouse has something picked up and is on top of the drop-box. Since the big is defined first, it will check for that one and not for the two inside it.

Comment: Hi @wouter140, do you have any idea to enable "interior" drop zones inside the "main" zone?